# Массивы в select()

Tags: c++, winsock

Функция `select` принимает 3 массива: для чтения, записи, исключений, если я не ошибаюсь.

Как это понимать? Для чтения значит я должен получить пакет который мне был отправлен? А для записи как понимать? а для исключений?

Comment: что за функция? исходники можно? 
я так представляю: первый аргумент - массив откуда будет читать, второй аргумент - массив, куда будет записывать
3й - массив, куда будет класть исключения и все это передать на вверх по ссылке

Comment: Я думаю тут неправильно интерпретировали описание ф-ции select из библиотеки winsock. По-моему найти описание с примерами в сети не сложно.

Answer (score 3):

В каждый массив передается список сокетов (в каком именно виде - это другой вопрос, под виндой и линуксом на уровне кода по разному, но макросы все скрывают), для которых нужно ждать событий.

Первый массив определяет список сокетов, для которых интересует чтение. Если на одном из сокетов появлятся данные, select сработает и эти данные можно **сразу прочитать**. То есть, не нужно делать ожидание, треды и тому подобное.

Второй массив предназначен  для событий о возможности записи. Да, как оказывается, в сокет не всегда можно писать. В сокете есть буфер на запись, и если клиент с той стороны не успевает вычитывать данные, то просто так быстро писать не получится. Очень часто делают буфер, который хранит все данные на отправку и по факту доступности сокета на запись, вызывается функция send, которая отправит данные и возвратит кол-во отправленных байтов (да, send не объязан отправить весь буфер), после этого с буфера удаляется нужное кол-во байт.

Третий набор используется редко (в своей практике я его не использовал никогда). По этим сокетам приходят ошибки и OOB (данные вне основного потока). Обычно ошибки приходят при вызове функции connect в неблокирующем режиме. OOB - это возможность послать по TCP данные "вне очереди".

Зачем все так сложно? Просто при таком подходе можно сделать всю работу с множествами клиентов в одном потоке. И если клиенты "медленные", то это будет работать хорошо даже на самом медленном железе. Альтернативная реализация с тредом на каждого клиента будет потреблять больше ресурсов и тратить много времени на переключение контекста.

Также нужно помнить, что виндовый select не поддерживает больше FD_SETSIZE сокетов ([msdn говорит](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), что сейчас это 64, но его можно поменять).

По факту часто пишут код, который добавляет сокеты для чтения select, а вместо остальных пишут null. Саму запись делают блокирующей. Почему так? да просто так проще писать (но это не говорит, что так правильно).

Comment: У меня вопрос... При постановке на отправку, предположим, send не успел отправить все предыдущие данные. Хотите сказать, что постановка нового сообщения в буфер не будет произведена? Что невозможно будет отправить новые данные, поставив их следом за частично отправленными?

Comment: где то так. Читаем в msdn `If no buffer space is available within the transport system to hold the data to be transmitted, send will block unless the socket has been placed in nonblocking mode. ` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx

То есть, если сокет блокирующий (состояние по умолчанию) и в буфере отправки нет места, то send будет заблокирован. Как только буфер освободиться, данные перекочуют туда.